# curl http auth work perfect in command line but on php not

Tags: php, authentication, curl, http-authentication

Hello i have command line code:

```
curl 'http://192.168.0.1:80/' -H 'Authorization: Basic my_auth'
```

In php:

```
$process = curl_init($ip);
//just for "shore"
            curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array(
              "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ":" . $password)
            ));
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login . ":" . $password);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

            $return = curl_exec($process);
```

in result i see: 401...
In apache2 log:

> - HTTP 1.0, assume close after body < HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized < Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 09:27:20 GMT < Server: Boa/0.94.13 <
>     Connection: close < WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="service" <
>     Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 < Set-Cookie:
>     SESSIONID=068054d0; <
> - Closing connection 53
> - Issue another request to this URL: ''
> - Hostname was found in DNS cache
> - Trying 192.168.0.1...
> - Connected to 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) port 80 (#54)
> - Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
>
>   > GET / HTTP/1.0 Authorization: Basic my_code Host: 192.168.0.1 Accept: */*
> - HTTP 1.0, assume close after body < HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized < Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 09:27:20 GMT < Server: Boa/0.94.13 <
>     Connection: close
> - Authentication problem. Ignoring this. < WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="service" < Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 <
>     Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=068054d0; <
> - Closing connection 54

Comment: Oh my god , huge mistake ))) "shore" => "sure") sry for my bad english

Comment: SOLVED:

curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiefile.txt');

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you send Basic Auth using curl. For Basic, the expected header is `Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded string>` where the string encoded is `:. The way to do this OOTB with curl (assuming no other configurations) is with the "-u" switch. Example:

```
curl -u "user:pass" http://<endpoint>/
```

If you send the header "manually" you have to base64 encode it yourself first.

Now, your PHP code is correct and your `curl` call incorrect. This implies there is an issue with how the service is interpreting `Authorization`.